# I am trying to create a login view that works for Customuser. Presently,the Loginform just redirects even when the fields are empty /incorrect input

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I have allauth installed to handle the login yet, I don't seem to find a breakthrough with having a proper login as the redirect just takes everyone to the destination page without any authentication.. The signup works fine as I can see created users in the admin.

**Settings.py**

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'useraccount',
'crispy_forms',
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',

'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
```

### Forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from useraccount.models import CustomUser as User
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password1']
```

### **Views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout , login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm,LoginForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.http import request , HttpResponseRedirect

def login_request(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if form.is_valid ():
       user = form.get_user ()
       user = authenticate ( email=email , password=password )
       login ( request , user )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard'))
else:
    form = LoginForm ()
    return render ( request=request ,
                template_name="useraccount/login.html" ,
                context={"form": form} )'
```

### **Urls.py**

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path , include
   from useraccount import views as c
   from useraccount import views as m
   from useraccount import views as a
   from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

   app_name = 'useraccount'

   urlpatterns = [
       path ( 'admin/' , admin.site.urls ) ,
       path ( '' , a.index , name='index'),
       path ( 'login/' , m.login_request , name='login' ) ,
       path ( 'signup/' , c.register , name='create' ) ,
       path ( 'logout/' , m.logout_request , name='logout' ) ,

       path ( 'dashboard/' , m.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

       path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),


]
```

### **Login.html**

```
{% extends 'useraccount/blank.html' %}


{% block title %}
Pinterest
{% endblock %}



{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block Content %}
 <div class="forming-container">
    <form method="post">

{% csrf_token %}


  <div class="mb-3">
  <input type="email" class="form-control btn-radius" id="exampleFormControlInput1" 
  placeholder="Email"> {{form.email}} </input>
    </br>
     <input type="password" class="form-control btn-radius" id="exampleFormControlInput2" 
  placeholder="Password"> {{form.password1}} </input>

    </div>

    <input class="btn d-block bg-red btn-radius text-white" type="submit" value="Continue" >
         </form>

    </div>
    <h4>OR</h4>
    <div class="social-sign d-flex mb-3">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook text-white mr-2 ml-2"></i>
    <a href="www.facebook.com" class="text-white"> Continue with facebook</a>
    </div>
    <div class="google-sign d-flex">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/www-daniekeys-com/image/upload/v1625758543/google- 
 img-removebg-preview_qm4mgu.png" alt="" class="g-img">
  <a href="www.google.com" class="text-dark"> Continue with google</a>
 </div>
 <div class="agreement">
  <p class="text-faded text-center text-reduce">
   By continuing, you agree to Pinterest's Terms of Service and acknowledge that you've read 
  our Privacy Policy
  </p>
  <div class="d-flex bold justiLog infy-content-center">
  <p class="text-dark ">
  <a href="/signup" class="text-dark">Need an account? Sign up now</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Views.py**

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('dashboard'))
            else:
                print('Invalid email or password')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request=request,
                      template_name="useraccount/login.html",
                      context={"form": form})
```

Try this. This will only login the user if not None (entered credentials  are correct)